# make: *** No rule to make target When Making Open Home Generated "ohNetGenerated" for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

I am trying to build the OpenHome Library for iOS from [ohNetGenerated](https://github.com/openhome/ohNetGenerated) and I am constantly getting the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dependencies/iOs-arm64/ohNet-iOs-arm64-Release/lib/libohNetCore.a', needed by `proxies'.  Stop.
```

I have followed the instructions and I have installed "Go". What is it for? When I run the command, I got and error saying:

```
go: unknown subcommand "fetch"
```

I don't understand too much about MakeFile files but I have reading a throw and I also found out that I neede MonoTouch and I install it.

Could someone say what I am doing wrong?

I a running the following command for making the file:

```
make iOs-arm64=1 Debug=1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to post what worked for me.

Using terminal in Mac:

1. I have upgrade my python using homebrew

   brew upgrade python
2. Clone ohnetdevtools into ohNetGenerated folder
3. Run the following command for fetching the tools needed. **The error was comming from here**

   ./go fetch --all --platform=iOs-arm64
4. Make the Bundle

   make iOs-arm64=1

   make iOs-arm64=1 debug=1